# How to orderBy duplicates in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Users table in Laravel and in the table I have a column of `Package` and `ReferredBy`.

ReferredBy field contains the referral email and many users can have the same referral email. This may sound like many to one relationship but instead of creating another table for referrals, we want to implement the functionality in our current flow.

I want to show the top 10 referral users descending order by the packages(1 basic package, 3 premium package).

How can I achieve this using Laravel eloquent or DB query?
I am able to filter the referral email using the following code

```php
 $TopReferrals = User::where('isVerified', TRUE)
                 ->select('Referred_By')
                 ->selectRaw('count(Referred_By) as Ref')
                 ->groupBy('Referred_By')
                 ->orderBy('Ref', 'DESC')
                 ->get();
```

Expected Output:
1. [User With The Most Referrals]
.
.
.

Comment: It is a one to many relationship which does mean you don't need a pivot table. That being said can you show us what you've tried so far and/or more details on your structure? In its current state this question is impossible to answer

Comment: Please provide sample data along with your expected result set in your question. It would be great if you can include DDL